# MySQL Nested Select Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, nested

Ok, so I have the following query:

```
SELECT MIN(`date`), `player_name`
FROM `player_playtime`
GROUP BY `player_name`
```

I then need to use this result inside the following query:

```
SELECT DATE(`date`) , COUNT(DISTINCT  `player_name`)
FROM  `player_playtime /*Use previous query result here*/`
GROUP BY DATE( `date`) DESC LIMIT 60
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What is the datatype of column `date`?

Comment: `datetime`. T I's solution worked perfectly. :-)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You just need to write the first query as a subquery (derived table), inside parentheses, pick an alias for it (`t` below) and alias the columns as well.

The `DISTINCT` can also be safely removed as the internal `GROUP BY` makes it redundant:

```
SELECT DATE(`date`) AS `date` , COUNT(`player_name`) AS `player_count`
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(`date`) AS `date`, `player_name`
    FROM `player_playtime`
    GROUP BY `player_name`
) AS t
GROUP BY DATE( `date`) DESC LIMIT 60 ;
```

Since the `COUNT` is now obvious that is only counting rows of the derived table, you can replace it with `COUNT(*)` and further simplify the query:

```
SELECT t.date , COUNT(*) AS player_count
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(MIN(`date`)) AS date
    FROM player_playtime
    GROUP BY player_name
) AS t
GROUP BY t.date DESC LIMIT 60 ;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: [#1054 - Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'] Any ideas?

Comment: That might be because `date` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL