# Nested queries and Join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

As a beginner with SQL, I’m ok to do simple tasks but I’m struggling right now with multiple nested queries. 
My problem is that I have 3 tables like this:

a `Case` table:

```
id   nd    date                  username
--------------------------------------------
1    596   2016-02-09 16:50:03   UserA
2    967   2015-10-09 21:12:23   UserB
3    967   2015-10-09 22:35:40   UserA
4    967   2015-10-09 23:50:31   UserB
5    580   2017-02-09 10:19:43   UserA
```

a `Value` table:

```
case_id   labelValue_id    Value          Type
-------------------------------------------------
1         3633             2731858342     X
1         124              ["864","862"]  X
1         8981             -2.103         X
1         27               443            X
...       ...              ...            ...
2         7890             232478         X
2         765              0.2334         X
...       ...              ...            ...
```

and a `Label` table:

```
id     label
----------------------
3633   Value of W             
124    Value of X   
8981   Value of Y     
27     Value of Z
```

Obviously, I want to join these tables. So I can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
from Case, Value, Label
where Case.id= Value.case_id
and Label.id = Value.labelValue_id
```

but I get pretty much everything whereas I would like to be more specific.

What I want is to do some filtering on the `Case` table and then use the resulting id's to join the two other tables. I'd like to:

1. Filter the `Case.nd`'s such that if there is serveral instances of the same nd, take the oldest one,
2. Limit the number of nd's in the query. For example, I want to be able to join the tables for just 2, 3, 4 etc... different nd.
3. Use this query to make a join on the `Value` and `Label` table.

For example, the output of the queries 1 and 2 would be:

```
id   nd    date                  username
--------------------------------------------
1    596   2016-02-09 16:50:03   UserA
2    967   2015-10-09 21:12:23   UserB
```

if I ask for 2 different nd. The nd 967 appears several times but we take the oldest one.

In fact, I think I found out how to do all these things but I can't/don't know how to merge them.

To select the oldest nd, I can do someting like:

```
select min((date)), nd,id 
    from Case
    group by nd
```

Then, to limit the number of nd in the output, I found this (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049702/create-a-sql-query-to-retrieve-most-recent-records) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964640/mysql-nested-select-query)) :

```
select *,
@num := if(@type <> t.nd, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
@type := t.nd as dummy
    from(
        select min((date)), nd,id 
        from Case
        group by nd
        ) as t
        group by t.nd
        having row_number <= 2 -- number of output
```

It works but I feel it's getting slow.

Finally, when I try to make a join with this subquery and with the two other tables, the processing keeps going on for ever.

During my research, I could find answers for every part of the problem but I can't merge them. Also, for the "counting" problem, where I want to limit the number of nd, I feel it's kind of far-fetch.

I realize this is a long question but I think I miss something and I wanted to give details as much as possible.

Comment: Start with any basic book or tutorial. Look especially at JOINs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally, here is what worked well for me:

```
select *
from (
        select *
        from Case
        join (
            select nd as T_ND, date as T_date
            from Case
            where nd in (select distinct nd from Case)
            group by T_ND Limit 5 -- <========= Limit of nd's
        ) as t
        on Case.nd = t.T_ND
        where date = (select min(date) 
                                from Case
                                where nd = t.T_ND)
    ) as subquery

    join Value 
        on Value.context_id = subquery.id
    join Label
        on Label.id = Value.labelValue_id
```

Thank you @charlesbretana for leading me on the right track :).

Answer (score 0):

to filter the case table to eliminate all but oldest nds,

```
select * from [case] c
where date = (Select min(date) from case
              where nd = c.nd)
```

then just join this to the other tables:

```
select * from [case] c
   join value v on v.Case_id = c.Id
   join label l on l.Id = v.labelValue_id
where date = (Select min(date) from [case]
              where nd = c.nd)
```

to limit it to a certain number of records, there is a mysql specific command, I think it called `Limit`

```
select * from [case] c
   join value v on v.Case_id = c.Id
   join label l on l.Id = v.labelValue_id
where date = (Select min(date) from [case]
              where nd = c.nd)
Limit 4 -- <=== will limit return result set to 4 rows
```

if you only want records for the top N values of nd, then the Limit goes on a subquery restricting what values of nd to retrieve:

```
select * from [case] c
   join value v on v.Case_id = c.Id
   join label l on l.Id = v.labelValue_id
where date = (Select min(date) from [case]
              where nd = c.nd)
   and nd In (select distinct nd from [case]
              order by nd desc Limit N)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, the join part helps me. However, for the limit part I think wasn't clear enough. I update the post and the `Value` table. For a `Case.nd` linked with the `Case.id`, I can get like 5000 values in the `Value` table. So, my point is not to limit the number of row (a `Limit 4` allows me to see the first 4 values for a specific nd), but really the number of nd that will be processed. I hope it will make sense.

Comment: yes, I understand,  then you need another predicate restriction on the case table.... but you have to specify *which* nd values to include then... assuming you want the *highest* n values,  I will examine another solution

Comment: Thank you! however I get this error "Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'. I'm on SQL V5.7.17. But apparently, we can use JOIN instead of IN. I'm working on it, I think I'm getting close !

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I just check everything.