# How to create MySQL nested query with DISTINCT and COUNT

Tags: mysql

I have one mySQL table here with some data.

[image: mySQL table here]

Before asking for help I tried [MySQL Nested Select Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964640/mysql-nested-select-query) before, but it's not working for me.

So, what I want to do is to list the total of the dir_id with more doc_id. The table should have only two columns as a result. dir_id and total. In this case, the table results shall have for the 1st-row dir_id = 3 and total = 3. In other words, dir_id 3, has 3 doc_id.

I tried to make use of DISTINCT and COUNT to construct a nested query as follow:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), AS total `dir_id` 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT dir_id, doc_id 
    FROM `dir_subdir` 
    ORDER BY `dir_subdir`.`dir_id` DESC)
```

Here is the [message error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkkr3.png) after running the query. Unfortunately, it is not clear for me, so I cannot fix it.

Any help will be grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Did you get an error? You should share the exact text of the error if you did (hint: you did get an error, if the query you show is transcribed accurately).

Comment: I posted the MySQL message error as an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `GROUP BY dir_id`. You also have the comma misplaced.

You can do this without the subquery using `COUNT(DISTINCT column)`

```
SELECT dir_id, COUNT(DISTINCT doc_id) AS total
FROM dir_subdir
GROUP BY dir_id
ORDER BY dir_id DESC
```